# getting a papers references using Elsevier Scopus API

Tags: python, api, reference, citations, scopus

I'm using the Scopus API made by Elsevier. 
http://dev.elsevier.com/sc_apis.html

I've written a short python scrip to extract information about papers such as the title, DOI number and the DOI numbers of papers citing the paper in question.

However what I would really like is to be able to extract the DOI numbers of papers that are referenced in the paper I'm extracting information from.

Here is a the important parts of my code so far

```
paper_info_search = requests.get(api_resource + 'query=doi(10.1016/j.fusengdes.2015.04.018)', headers=headers)
```

This extracts lots of information on the paper (title, authors etc)

```
citations_of_paper = requests.get(api_resource + 'query=refeid(' + EID + ')', headers=headers)
```

The get the list of papers citing the paper in question

Does anyone know how to get the reference that appear in this paper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having the same problem, I sent an email to the API team and was told that you cannot get the references as search results using the scopus search API.

However you can get the information through the abstract retrieval API http://api.elsevier.com/documentation/AbstractRetrievalAPI.wadl using the 'REF' view. The query I'm using right now looks like this

```
https://api.elsevier.com/content/abstract/EID:[]?apiKey=[]&view=REF
```

Comment: i got this error: The requestor is not authorized to access the requested view or fields of the resource

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this question, one other easy way to do this is by using the Abstract Retrieval of the [pybliometrics](https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/AbstractRetrieval.html) package.

Simply follow whats written there and you get all reference information for a given document.

Comment: The weblink does not exist anymore. Can you please modify your answer to include the relevant details here itself?